# Scrub data from xml using c# and xpath

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I am trying to delete/Scrub few elements from the xml using c# with the help of xpaths. I am trying to replace the value of social_security_number with "Scrubbed" in both the child tags named "Customers". But my program is landing in many errors. Please correct me.

xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<LoanApplications xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="12345" bundle_id="12225" version="1.0">
    <LoanApplication payment_call="False" version="1.0" app_status="I" perform_dupe_check="1"   bundle_id="12225"  UpdateReviewed="True">
            <Customers id = "12" name =  "krish" ssn = "123456789">
    </LoanApplication>      
    <LoanApplication deal_type="RESPONSE"  payment_call="True" version="1.0"  app_status="I" perform_dupe_check="1"   bundle_id="12225"  UpdateReviewed="True">
    <Customers id = "12" name =  "krish" ssn = "123456789">
    </LoanApplication>
</LoanApplications>
```

Program :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("mytestfile.xml");
            doc.SelectSingleNode("/LoanApplications/LoanApplication[@deal_type="%DealTypeALL%"]/LoanApplicationStates/LoanApplicationState/Customers/Customer[@customer_id="%CustIDALL%"]/").Attributes["social_security_number"].InnerText = "Scrubbed";

            doc.Save("mytestfile.xml");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\Input\\2015\\09\\03\\mytestfile.xml"));
foreach (var customer in doc.Descendants("Customer"))
{
    var ssn = customer.Attribute("social_security_number");
    if (ssn != null)
    {
        ssn.Value = "scrubbed";
    }
}

doc.Save("file.xml");
```

Comment: It is resulting error in line  doc.Load("mytestfile.xml");   

cannot use local variable 'doc' before it is declared.

Comment: This is the error I am getting :

A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There is no Unicode byte order mark. Cannot switch to Unicode.

Comment: var doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\Input\\2015\\09\\03\\mytestfile.xml");

This is my input string

Comment: Your XML is not correctly formatted, make sure the "Customers" tag is closed. I had to fix it in order to test. Notice the "/>" in the end here <Customers id = "12" name =  "krish" ssn = "123456789" />

Comment: Is it because the customer is a descendant of LoanApplication ? And the LoanApplication Node is differentiated using deal type = 'Recommended' or 'Requested'

Comment: Sorry, this is a samle xml I have created. But in my real xml they are present with "/>" . But still it is the same error. Also to mention there are many child nodes to <customer> too. Will that change the code ?

Comment: Nw I get the error "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocment.Parse(String) has some invalid arguments.'"

My file name is :  20150903143222.28405_Always_1441305129727.xml

CAn you please advise?

Comment: the parse takes the input format as XDocument.Parse(String Text, LoadOptions options).

Do I need to add anything of type LoadOptions ?

Comment: And if I just go with  var doc =  XDocument.Parse("C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\Input\\2015\\09\\03\\20150903143222.28405_Always_1441305129727.xml");


Error : Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: can you post xml sample you're trying? I tried the one you posted above and it works fine

Comment: Please check the question now; I have posted the xml I am working on. The XML  am working is of more than 1000 lines. I have posted an abridged version of it

Comment: I tried your latest sample with my code listed above and it works fine

Comment: The problem is with the first line

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>

If I change it to <?xml version="1.0"?> your code is working.

But there are 1000s of files like these , is there any work around to make it work for the way it is now ?

Comment: It worked when i Used : System.IO.File.ReadAllText

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have few needed nodes instead of one. Thus, you should use `SelectNodes` instead of `SelectSingleNode` method.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("mytestfile.xml");

var ssns = doc.SelectNodes("LoanApplications/LoanApplication/LoanApplicationStates/LoanApplicationState/Customers/Customer/@social_security_number");

foreach (XmlAttribute ssn in ssns)
    ssn.InnerText = "Scrubbed";

doc.Save("mytestfile.xml");
```

You can use shorter XPath with descendants. But it has less performance.

```
var ssns = doc.SelectNodes("//Customer/@social_security_number");
```

Comment: I am getting error at 

doc.Load("C:\\Users\\spechetti\\Desktop\\Input\\2015\\09\\03\\20150903143222.28405_Always_1441305129727.xml");

Comment: Error is : An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There is no Unicode byte order mark. Cannot switch to Unicode.

Comment: @HadoopAddict - Probably you have invalid xml. Fix your xml.

Comment: The problem is with the first line

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>

If I change it to <?xml version="1.0"?> your code is working.

But there are 1000s of files like these , is there any work around to make it work for the way it is now ?

Comment: @HadoopAddict - I repeat: your xml is invalid. Where did you get it? I think it is saved in another encoding than utf-16. To avoid this, do not use simple text editors like Notepad to create and edit xml. Use specialized xml editors.

Answer (score 0):

This is real easy with xml linq

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> ss = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attribute("social_security_number") != null).ToList();
            foreach (XElement s in ss)
            {
                s.Attribute("social_security_number").Value = "Scrubbed";
            }
        }
    }
}
```